# Tooltip on Outlook Add-in Ribbon

Tags: vsto, add-in, ribbon

I created a outlook add-in using VSTO 2008. I didn't create a separate ribbon/group for this add-in. Instead VSTO automatically create the add-in button in the built-in Ribbon when Outlook starts.
Now how do I customize the tooltip of that add-in icon?

Here is the snippet to add label and icon for my add-in

```
[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass("IPM.Note.DougForm")]
    [Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionName("Doug.Note.FormTest")]
    public class QMemoRegionFactory : QRegionFactory, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.IFormRegionFactory
    {
        public DougFormTest()
        {
            this._Manifest.FormRegionName = "DougForm";
            this._Manifest.Icons.Page = global::DougForm.OutlookAddin.Properties.Resources.DougIcon_big;
        }
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Does you app generate any ribbon XML that you know of?  The property names that can set tooltip text for buttons on a Ribbon are ScreenTip and SuperTip.

Alternatively, create your own custom ribbon XML and set the label, icon, and screentip to be whatever you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866(VS.80).aspx